# SharePoint REST and DataTables.net (SP2103)

Tags: rest, sharepoint, datatables, sharepoint-2013

I am fairly new to SP and we are still using an old version, so looking for some new functionality to bring year experience up...  sorry if this has been asked and I missed the thread.

I have been looking for a way to get a better presented lists, and I found a great article (https://info.summit7systems.com/blog/who-needs-a-data-view-web-part-sharepoint-rest-and-datatables-net) about using DataTables and REST.

The solution works great is simple to use, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make a searched / filtered list item selectable where a field can have a link to open the it in the Default Display Form page (DispForm.aspx).

Any pointers or examples would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Hack-67,

I understand you want to make a column as hyperlink. If so, you can take a reference of below API:

- [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render#Examples)

```html
$('#example').dataTable({
   "data": responseObj,
   select: true,
   "columns": [
      { "data": "information" }, 
      { 
         "data": "weblink",
         "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
            if(type === 'display'){
                data = '<a href="' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
            }
            
            return data;
         }
      } 
   ]
});
```

And if you want to make the row selectable, you may use below options:

- https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/simple.html

More references:

- https://jsfiddle.net/cqamc695/1/